# Free Wpf scheduler control

Tags: wpf, controls, scheduler

Is there any free scheduler control for WPF?  I found [ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ScheduleWPF/) and [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/scheduler.aspx)

but they are not free. I need something with equivalent functionality that I can use in school project.

Answer (score 2):

As it is a school project your use of it would be limited. I know the guys at Telerik are very helpful. It may be worth contacting them with a view to "lending" you a license for your project. It is, after all, good for them because you'll then recommend them to others. Sort of like an "educational license".

Answer (score 0):

Codeplex has a open source control for Scheduler Control See.. http://wpfschedule.codeplex.com/ . And this control has daily view only

Answer (score -1):

There is also a control by [Devcomponents](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar-wpf/WPFScheduleControl.aspx)

You could compare prices and buy.